# God Rays / Light Beams not showing up in Cycles. Tried in different Scene and it worked. Whats the cause?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, volumetrics

So I have a scene as below and I was trying all day yesterday to get a nice lighting effect and it didnt work. From disabling the hdri, playing with the sun strength, angle, spot lights etc.

Today I jsut set up a room with a hole in a wall, 2 bars in front, a volume and a sun light and it worked. Why does it not work in my scene? I think I am just missing something or some settings are wrong.

Scene and light settings:

[image]

Sun Settings with the scene and plane to create light beams:

[image]

Volume settings:
[image]

Result witht he above ssettings and no hdri:

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share the cube + walls + light?

Comment: How can I provide you the blend file?

Comment: you can upload and copy paste the URL it will generate: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/561c3eb766354a98a473ad35431f880d

Comment: it works fine for me so I'm not sure what's happening for you: https://zupimages.net/up/22/13/025m.jpg